# Creating Visualisations of Random Graphs

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs

I've got some code in C that produces a whole load of random geometric graphs and finds the proportion that percolate in order to estimate the full connection probability.

However I need to produce some kind of visualisation i.e. images of the graphs (not all of them, essentially just one example). Moreover I need to check (not essential) that the graphs produced look right (according to my domain).

Does anyone know of a good way of taking an adjacency matrix and a position matrix (the nodes have positions in Euclidean space) and producing some kind of visualisation?

Sorry to post this here, I thought someone from maths may have done this before.

Cheers.

Comment: If you want to do it in Matlab have a look here: http://www.mathworks.nl/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/graph-createrandomgraph.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to Mathematica, then you just need to perform
$$
\verb bAdjacencyGraph[A,VertexCoordinates->Coordinates]b 
$$
where $A$ is your adjacency matrix, and $\verb bCoordinatesb$    is a list of the form 
$$
\{\{x_1,y_1\},\{x_2,y_2\},\ldots,\{x_n,y_n\}\}
$$

Comment: I need to have the nodes live inside a circle with a circular obstacle at its centre - is this easy enough to add to the graph visualisation?

Comment: Yes, it is (probably) easy, you should read the help for Graph, e.g. However, I understood from you question that you need to draw the graph with your own coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply need to visualize an adjacency matrix, you can use a tool like [Gephi](https://gephi.org/). You can write a simple MATLAB script that would write your adjacency matrix and position matrix into a gdf file and then use Gephi to visualize. Alternatively, you can even import your data from an Excel sheet or specify internally.

Hope this helps!